# How do I set up a simple filebeat to ES cluster?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, kibana, filebeat

I'm trying for the first time to set up a cluster where filebeat sends logs to ES which I can view in Kibana. All I'm trying to do is see the logs I write into the file `/tmp/aaa.log` in Kibana. I'm getting a little lost in all the configuration. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong based on the configuration files below?

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
---
version: '3.6'
services:  
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${TAG}
    container_name: elasticsearch
    ports: ['9200:9200']
    networks: ['stack']
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    volumes:
      - 'es_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data'

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${TAG}
    container_name: kibana
    ports: ['5601:5601']
    networks: ['stack']
    depends_on: ['elasticsearch']
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false

  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:${TAG}
    container_name: logstash
    networks: ['stack']
    depends_on: ['elasticsearch']
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false

  filebeat:
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:${TAG}
    container_name: filebeat
    volumes:
      - /tmp/filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
    networks: ['stack']
    depends_on: ['elasticsearch', 'kibana']

networks: {stack: {}}
```

And here's `filebeat.yml`:

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- input_type: log
  paths:
    - /tmp/aaa.log

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ['elasticsearch:9200']
```

And I run this with `TAG=5.6.13 docker-compose up` (I have to use ES version 5).

Here are the logs:

```
2018/11/27 16:20:57.165350 beat.go:297: INFO Home path: [/usr/share/filebeat] Config path: [/usr/share/filebeat] Data path: [/usr/share/filebeat/data] Logs path: [/usr/share/filebeat/logs]
2018/11/27 16:20:57.165389 beat.go:192: INFO Setup Beat: filebeat; Version: 5.6.13
2018/11/27 16:20:57.165502 output.go:263: INFO Loading template enabled. Reading template file: /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.template.json
2018/11/27 16:20:57.166247 output.go:274: INFO Loading template enabled for Elasticsearch 2.x. Reading template file: /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.template-es2x.json
2018/11/27 16:20:57.167063 output.go:286: INFO Loading template enabled for Elasticsearch 6.x. Reading template file: /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.template-es6x.json
2018/11/27 16:20:57.167554 metrics.go:23: INFO Metrics logging every 30s
2018/11/27 16:20:57.167888 client.go:128: INFO Elasticsearch url: http://elasticsearch:9200
2018/11/27 16:20:57.167909 outputs.go:108: INFO Activated elasticsearch as output plugin.
2018/11/27 16:20:57.168015 publish.go:300: INFO Publisher name: 34df7198d027
2018/11/27 16:20:57.168185 async.go:63: INFO Flush Interval set to: 1s
2018/11/27 16:20:57.168194 async.go:64: INFO Max Bulk Size set to: 50
2018/11/27 16:20:57.168512 beat.go:233: INFO filebeat start running.
2018/11/27 16:20:57.168546 registrar.go:68: INFO No registry file found under: /usr/share/filebeat/data/registry. Creating a new registry file.
2018/11/27 16:20:57.174446 registrar.go:106: INFO Loading registrar data from /usr/share/filebeat/data/registry
2018/11/27 16:20:57.174491 registrar.go:123: INFO States Loaded from registrar: 0
2018/11/27 16:20:57.174515 crawler.go:38: INFO Loading Prospectors: 1
2018/11/27 16:20:57.174633 prospector_log.go:65: INFO Prospector with previous states loaded: 0
2018/11/27 16:20:57.174715 prospector.go:124: INFO Starting prospector of type: log; id: 16715230261889747 
2018/11/27 16:20:57.174726 crawler.go:58: INFO Loading and starting Prospectors completed. Enabled prospectors: 1
2018/11/27 16:20:57.174735 registrar.go:236: INFO Starting Registrar
2018/11/27 16:20:57.174754 sync.go:41: INFO Start sending events to output
2018/11/27 16:20:57.174788 spooler.go:63: INFO Starting spooler: spool_size: 2048; idle_timeout: 5s
2018/11/27 16:21:27.168018 metrics.go:39: INFO Non-zero metrics in the last 30s: registrar.writes=1
2018/11/27 16:21:57.167828 metrics.go:34: INFO No non-zero metrics in the last 30s
2018/11/27 16:22:27.167772 metrics.go:34: INFO No non-zero metrics in the last 30s
2018/11/27 16:22:57.167974 metrics.go:34: INFO No non-zero metrics in the last 30s
2018/11/27 16:23:27.167752 metrics.go:34: INFO No non-zero metrics in the last 30s
2018/11/27 16:23:57.167944 metrics.go:34: INFO No non-zero metrics in the last 30s
2018/11/27 16:24:27.167943 metrics.go:34: INFO No non-zero metrics in the last 30s
2018/11/27 16:24:32.039122 filebeat.go:267: INFO Stopping filebeat
2018/11/27 16:24:32.039158 crawler.go:90: INFO Stopping Crawler
2018/11/27 16:24:32.039166 crawler.go:100: INFO Stopping 1 prospectors
2018/11/27 16:24:32.039187 prospector.go:180: INFO Prospector ticker stopped
2018/11/27 16:24:32.039187 prospector.go:137: INFO Prospector channel stopped because beat is stopping.
2018/11/27 16:24:32.039198 prospector.go:232: INFO Stopping Prospector: 16715230261889747
2018/11/27 16:24:32.039215 crawler.go:112: INFO Crawler stopped
2018/11/27 16:24:32.039223 spooler.go:101: INFO Stopping spooler
2018/11/27 16:24:32.039249 registrar.go:291: INFO Stopping Registrar
2018/11/27 16:24:32.039264 registrar.go:248: INFO Ending Registrar
2018/11/27 16:24:32.041518 metrics.go:51: INFO Total non-zero values:  registrar.writes=2
2018/11/27 16:24:32.041533 metrics.go:52: INFO Uptime: 3m34.878904973s
2018/11/27 16:24:32.041538 beat.go:237: INFO filebeat stopped.
2018/11/28 08:43:17.481376 beat.go:297: INFO Home path: [/usr/share/filebeat] Config path: [/usr/share/filebeat] Data path: [/usr/share/filebeat/data] Logs path: [/usr/share/filebeat/logs]
2018/11/28 08:43:17.481411 beat.go:192: INFO Setup Beat: filebeat; Version: 5.6.13
2018/11/28 08:43:17.481500 output.go:263: INFO Loading template enabled. Reading template file: /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.template.json
2018/11/28 08:43:17.482638 output.go:274: INFO Loading template enabled for Elasticsearch 2.x. Reading template file: /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.template-es2x.json
2018/11/28 08:43:17.483675 metrics.go:23: INFO Metrics logging every 30s
2018/11/28 08:43:17.483780 output.go:286: INFO Loading template enabled for Elasticsearch 6.x. Reading template file: /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.template-es6x.json
2018/11/28 08:43:17.484701 client.go:128: INFO Elasticsearch url: http://elasticsearch:9200
2018/11/28 08:43:17.484745 outputs.go:108: INFO Activated elasticsearch as output plugin.
2018/11/28 08:43:17.484844 publish.go:300: INFO Publisher name: 34df7198d027
2018/11/28 08:43:17.484975 async.go:63: INFO Flush Interval set to: 1s
2018/11/28 08:43:17.484982 async.go:64: INFO Max Bulk Size set to: 50
2018/11/28 08:43:17.485563 beat.go:233: INFO filebeat start running.
2018/11/28 08:43:17.485607 registrar.go:85: INFO Registry file set to: /usr/share/filebeat/data/registry
2018/11/28 08:43:17.485630 registrar.go:106: INFO Loading registrar data from /usr/share/filebeat/data/registry
2018/11/28 08:43:17.485656 registrar.go:123: INFO States Loaded from registrar: 0
2018/11/28 08:43:17.485688 crawler.go:38: INFO Loading Prospectors: 1
2018/11/28 08:43:17.485758 prospector_log.go:65: INFO Prospector with previous states loaded: 0
2018/11/28 08:43:17.485840 prospector.go:124: INFO Starting prospector of type: log; id: 16715230261889747 
2018/11/28 08:43:17.485848 crawler.go:58: INFO Loading and starting Prospectors completed. Enabled prospectors: 1
2018/11/28 08:43:17.485881 sync.go:41: INFO Start sending events to output
2018/11/28 08:43:17.485898 registrar.go:236: INFO Starting Registrar
2018/11/28 08:43:17.485945 spooler.go:63: INFO Starting spooler: spool_size: 2048; idle_timeout: 5s
2018/11/28 08:43:47.483962 metrics.go:34: INFO No non-zero metrics in the last 30s
2018/11/28 08:44:17.484051 metrics.go:34: INFO No non-zero metrics in the last 30s
```

Comment: Please add more information regarding what happens when you docker-compose up. In what state the containers are, post docker-compose logs, if you can connect to your kibana instance, etc..

Comment: Kibana is reachable and all containers are up and running. I've added the logs to my original post.

Comment: You pretty much are not getting any records from your filebeat sources. Can you please run this command on your Kibana Dev Tools Console just to make sure nothing has been sent to ES: `GET _cat/indices`

Comment: Then please get into your filebeat container (`docker exec -it <container id|name> bash`) and please `cat /tmp/aaa.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake. I stupidly forgot to map the log file in `docker-compose.yml`.